# S3 Lifecycle Expiration: do object expiry/deletes cost money for SIA objects?

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm planning on deleting a large number of S3 Standard Infrequent Access (SIA) objects (over a hundred million), and want to ensure I won't get hit with a large bill. The plan is to use a lifecycle expiration to delete these objects.

1) is there any charge/cost for Lifecycle expirations for SIA objects? The pricing page lists a cost of $0.01/1000 for "Lifecycle Transitions", but the docs seem to imply "lifecycle transition" (moving to another storage class) and  "lifecycle expiry" (deleting objects) are two separate things. There is no price listed for "lifecycle expiry", but I'm not confident that means its free (or is it considered a transition for pricing purposes?).

2) is there any other charges/cost for deleting SIA objects using lifecycle expiry for SIA objects?

Thanks!

Comment: The only authoritative source claiming that the deletes caused by object expiration are free is this initial [AWS announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2011/12/27/amazon-s3-announces-object-expiration/). Setting a bounty on this question as it needs more attention.

Comment: @istepaniuk I have added an authoritative source.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ran this deletion without issue or unexpected charges. AWS did not consider deletes to be "lifecycle transitions", and deleting objects via lifecycle expiry didn't incur any additional charges for SIA or other classes.

Answer (score 5):

Object expiry is the process of an object being queued for asynchronous deletion by AWS.

We can state that *object expiry* is synonymous with *managed eventual object deletion*. It is not a lifecycle transition as there is no 'lifecycle' for the object to transition to; it is being deleted.

The official [Expiring Objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-expire-general-considerations.html) page states:

> **You are not charged for expiration** or the storage time associated with an object that has expired.

Object expiry/deletion is **free of charge**, regardless of the storage class.